# how to add description to the test in dbt

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, dbt

How to add description to the generic test which is usually written in yml so that I can see it in the DESCRIPTION field in dbt docs

in yml such tests are usually written like this but how to add a description to the test

```
        - name: desc
         description: "it is the description of the column but not the test"
          tests:
          - not_null:
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [Configurable description in yaml config for generic tests · Issue #3249 · dbt-labs/dbt-core · GitHub](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/3249)

Comment: The above-mentioned github issue was closed as being staled for too long :-/

Comment: Refer to the macro in this page https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/2578#issuecomment-1868473901